# Duda sobre el comportamiento de lc_time_names en MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

La documentación de MySQL indica que para controlar el lenguaje en que se presentan los nombres de días y de meses, así como sus abreviaciones se ha de usar `lc_time_names`.

De modo que para establecer esa configuración a castellano yo hago por ejemplo:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
```

Sin embargo, no leo nada en la documentación sobre **qué alcance tiene esa consulta**, o sea, si es efectiva solamente para ese contexto en que la ejecuto o si establece algún tipo de configuración definitiva en el manejador de base de datos hasta que se vuelva a cambiar por otra cosa.

**¿Cuál sería entonces el alcance de `SET lc_time_names`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al utilizar [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html) para modificar variables del sistema, puedes conseguir que:

- La modificación sea permanente usando `GLOBAL` (o `@@global.`), ya que establece el valor de la variable a nivel global.

  ```
  SET GLOBAL lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
  SET @@global.lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
  ```
- La modificación sea para la sesión (*"temporal"*), usando `SESSION` (o `@@session. o @@`), ya que establece el valor de la variable solo para sesión en curso.

  ```
  SET SESSION lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
  SET @@session.lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
  SET @@lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
  ```

*Notas:*

- `LOCAL` y `@@local.` son sinonimos de `SESSION` y `@@session.`
- Si no se agrega un modificador, `SET` cambia la variable para la sesión.

Comment: Gracias Marcos. ¿Y usado sin nada a qué corresponde?