# ¿Cómo se cambia el idioma de los datos de un CSV a la hora de exportarlo desde MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, date, csv, mysql-workbench

He usado las funciones de MySQL "DAYNAME(Date)" y "MONTHNAME(Date)".

He usado la sentencia "SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';" para poner los campos en español, pero el problema viene a la hora de exportar los datos en CSV. Los vuelve a colocar en inglés.

¿Hay alguna forma de que los datos que se generan sigan estando en español tal como lo veo en MySQL Workbench (software que uso para tal fin)?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: mira aca.. sera que el cvs corre en otra sesion??? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129542/324

Comment: He probado todo eso y sigue sin funcionar correctamente :/ pero gracias

Comment: ya encontraremos alguien que sepa entonces!

Comment: Yo uso `CONVERT( CAST(CONVERT( campo USING LATIN1) AS BINARY) USING UTF8) AS campo` , tal vez te sirva.

Comment: ¡Ha funcionado! Cambiando "LATIN1" por, de nuevo, "UTF8" ya aparecen las letras acentuadas (como "miércoles y sábado").

Muchísimas gracias